# How to convert a date format to different date format in java?

Tags: java, sql, database, date

i want to convert a date format to another format:

```
try {
    System.out.println("try block tai asche naki ?" + stockData.getTRANSDATE());
    SimpleDateFormat inFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    SimpleDateFormat outFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    date = inFmt.parse(stockData.getTRANSDATE().toString());
    System.out.println("conversion" +inFmt.parse(stockData.getTRANSDATE().toString()) );

    System.out.println("old date format ?" + date);
    //date1 = outFmt.format(date);
    System.out.println("new date format "+ outFmt.format(date));
    return template
    .queryForInt(
        "SELECT COUNT(TRANSDATE) FROM stockdata
         WHERE TRANSDATE= ? AND symbolname = ?",
    rowMapper,outFmt.format(date), SymbolName);
}
```

as i want to use it in a sql query its not working
please help me out how i will convert the date so i can use it in the db as outFmt.format(date) cant be resolved in DB query

Thanks

Comment: Is there an `Exception`?  (Or even a question?)

Answer (score 0):

Dateformat is for parsing string to java Date type or output date object to text with certain pattern.

In your case, you need a Date object for your query, not a String.

is this code working for you?

```
 return template
                    .queryForInt(
                            "SELECT COUNT(TRANSDATE) FROM stockdata WHERE TRANSDATE= ? AND symbolname = ?",
                            rowMapper,date, SymbolName);
```

Comment: if i take date then it will print in **yyyyMMddHHmmss** format 
not in **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"** format

Comment: @Aritra you are binding parameters for your query. You don't care about the date format is yyyymmdd or ddmmyyyy. if the object you are about to bind to your TRANSDATE is a java Date type, it is ok. btw, what data type have you defined in your database for column TRANSDATE? is it a DATE or DATETIME ?

Comment: Does Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForInt%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) also accept `java.util.Date`? That might be the problem...

Comment: @ kent its DATETIME fomat i saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using Spring's JdbcTemplate. Why don't you just bind a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of formatting it?

**UPDATE**:

I don't know what `stockData.getTRANSDATE()` is, but in order to convert it to `Timestamp`, do this:

```
Timestamp date = new TimeStamp(
  inFmt.parse(stockData.getTRANSDATE().toString()).getTime());
```

Then, pass it to Spring as a bind value, without formatting:

```
return template
    .queryForInt(
        "SELECT COUNT(TRANSDATE) FROM stockdata
         WHERE TRANSDATE= ? AND symbolname = ?",
    rowMapper, date, SymbolName);
```

Comment: @Aritra: What makes you think so?

Comment: @Aritra: I updated my answer. However, you should try 1-2 things yourself in the future